Evaluating options for sunken concrete pier
In our crawlspace we have a sunken concrete pier that is no longer touching the beam above it. I've shimmed some support there temporarily, but am looking at a more permanent solution.

A reputable foundation company gave me a couple quotes on how to repair it. One, they could pour a new concrete foundation (basically fix the current setup), although this comes with no warranty. Or they could, for a few thousand more, support this area with 1 or 2 Smart Jacks on a crushed stone base (with a 5 year warranty).
Curious about getting some feedback on these choices. On one hand, the Smart Jack option seems like it might be more long-term secure. On the other hand, I'm selling this house within 6 months most likely and the repair which doesn't stand out might actually work just as well and attract less concern from a future buyer. The foundation specialist had no concerns about the integrity of the ground underneath it or anything.

Unclear how a concrete pier could sink without a lack of integrity of the ground under it.

I guess if you were quite certain that it was simply incompetence (failure to properly compact fill and placing a pier on uncompacted fill) you might not have much concern for further lack of integrity...but in that case, longer post should fix it.

There was a root nearby that they speculated could be related. Also, there have been mice in the crawlspace before and this concrete footing is apparently just sitting on the soil surface (so some simple tunneling from mice underneath might be able to cause it to sink). Longer post would work except the concrete footing isn't level.

inject expanding grout under the under the footing pad
